# How to use an if statement in flask to render code only on a specific url

Tags: python, flask

I am sorry if this has been asked but I was unable to find the answer after searching stackoverflow.

Basically I am trying to use an if statement in my jinja2 template so that if the /login page is the current url, the modal for login is automatically opened. Reason is that every public page has the login modal, but when a url only available to authenticated users is loaded, I have it redirecting to a login (without having a unique page for /login, so /login shares the homepage template). So the modal needs to automatically open when on /login.

This is what I have been trying in my template:

```
{% if request.url == url_for('login') %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").modal('show');
});
</script>
{% endif %}
```

If I add that code to my template, without the if statement, it does work fine and every page load loads the page with the modal opened. My if statement is obviously the problem as none of the pages using that template including /login load with the modal open. I have tried many things to no avail. Any help with a proper if statement or perhaps a better way to achieve my goal would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance and apologies for the long winded explanation.

Comment: Try inspect a rendered template to see what the values of `{{ request.url }}` and `{{ url_for('login') }}` are? Are they what you expect?

Comment: Thanks!! Totally solved my problem. Result was:
/login
http://127.0.0.1:5000/login
so I changed my if statement to request.path instead of request.url, works perfectly now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to PGHE who commented on my question, the answer was very easy to find.
When inspecting the values of {{ request.url }} and {{ url_for('login') }} I had the following result:

```
/login 
127.0.0.1:5000/login
```

So I changed request.url from my if statement to request.path which got it to work perfectly.

Thank you PGHE